# E/UncaughtException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=100; index=-1

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

So I am creating a Habit tracker that adds a value everytime you check a checkbox on the viewHolder, the problem I am having is that when I have 6 or more habits on the list, the checkboxes dont work properly (They start checking in a random order) anymore and give me the error above.

I am using this on my recycler adapter:

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position){
        holder.nombre.setText(mHabitosList.get(position).getNombre());


          FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
          mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference("Habitos");
          FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
          if(user != null) {
              userId = user.getUid();
              habitosReference = mDatabaseReference.child(userId);

              habitosReference.child(mHabitosList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getHabitosId()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Habitos habitos = dataSnapshot.getValue(Habitos.class);
                        if(habitos != null) {
                            updateHabitosTotal[position] = habitos.getTotal();
                            checkBox1 = habitos.isCheckbox1();
                            checkBox2 = habitos.isCheckbox2();
                            checkBox3 = habitos.isCheckbox3();
                            checkBox4 = habitos.isCheckbox4();
                            checkBox5 = habitos.isCheckbox5();
                            checkListeners(holder, position);

                        }

                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                  }
              });
    }
```

On the check listener I have

```
private void checkListeners(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder) {
        holder.CB1.setChecked(checkBox1);
        holder.CB1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                {
                    if (holder.getAdapterPosition() != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        String HabitosId = mHabitosList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getHabitosId();
                        int total = mHabitosList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getTotal();
                        if (b) {
                            habitosReference.child(HabitosId).child("Checks").child(mDays[0]).setValue(true);
                            total++;
                        } else {
                            habitosReference.child(HabitosId).child("Checks").child(mDays[0]).setValue(false);
                            total--;
                        }
                        habitosReference.child(HabitosId).child("total").setValue(total);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
.... And the same for CB2,CB3,CB4,CB5..
```

My apologies for the code dump... Any kind of help would be highly appreciated! (:

Code Error:

> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   length=20; index=-1
>           at com.albot.focus.Adapters.HabitosAdapter$5.onCheckedChanged(HabitosAdapter.java:224)

Comment: Can you point out the line where the error occurs?

Comment: On the  updateHabitosTotal[holder.getAdapterPosition()] += 1; in the CheckListener(); I should mention that I created a   private int[] updateHabitosTotal = new int[20]; on the beggining of the Adapter..

Comment: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about debugging your app.

Answer (score 2):

Its already mentioned in the docs that `getAdapterPosition()` can return -1 or `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` if

1. Item has been removed from the adapter.
2. `RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` has been called after
   the last layout pass.
3. The `ViewHolder` has already been recycled.

so to avoid it, You should always check if `getAdapterPosition() != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` when item is clicked

Comment: The error is happening before the -1 so the -1 is an effect of the error and not the cause

Comment: in your comment you yourself said error is occuring in updateHabitosTotal[holder.getAdapterPosition()] += 1 , i can see a getAdapterPosition() call there

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't giving much code, or the error, im just going to make an educated guess.

Your problem is probably with the position variable, you need to outprint your position. mHabitList is 0 indexed, it starts at 0. My guess is that position isn't, try maybe subtracting 1 from position.

Comment: The rest of the adapter is business as usual.. Thats not it though :/

Comment: Ok, can you post the error + outprint of position and mHabitosList

Comment: When you check a checkbox other checkboxes get checked, when there are more than 6 holders; if there are 5 or less it works fine